# Progress Bar Java Empresarial

Tags: java, java-ee, progressbar

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con Java Empresarial y quería hacer una funcionalidad extra pero no tengo claro como se hace o incluso si se puede hacer, os cuento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este html en el cual introduzco un número y si le doy al botón de "Calcular" me calcula el factorial de ese número.

Por otro lado, si pongo un número y pongo un nombre en "Usuario" y le doy a "Guardar", me lanza un Servlet el cuál guarda ese número y el usuario en la base de datos.

El caso es que al realizar esta acción tarda unos segundos en escribir en la base de datos asi es que había pensado introducir un Progress Bar para que se vaya viendo como va el progreso de guardado pero no tengo muy claro como unir el aumento de la Progress Bar con la operación de guardado.

PD: El boton "Click me" lo unico que hace es iniciar la función de la progress bar simplemente para ver que funciona.

PD2: La aplicación funciona correctamente, lo único es que me gustaría poder meterle el progress bar jejeje

Os dejo el código de la progress bar y del guardado:

> Parte HTML y JS:

```
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button> 

            <div id="myProgress">
                <div id="myBar">
                </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                function move() {
                    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
                    var width = 1;
                    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
                    function frame() {
                        if (width >= 100) {
                            clearInterval(id);
                        } else {
                            width++;
                            elem.style.width = width + '%';
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
```

> Parte Servlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "GuardarServlet", urlPatterns = {"/GuardarServlet"})
public class GuardarServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String base , usuario;
    base = request.getParameter("base");
    usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");

    SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session s = sf.openSession();

    Factorial fact = new Factorial(); 
    fact.setBase(base);
    fact.setResultado(usuario); //Guarda en el campo resultado el nombre del usuario
    //Guardamos los datos en la base de datos
    s.beginTransaction();
    s.save(fact);
    s.getTransaction().commit();
    s.close();
    sf.close();



    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet GuardarServlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet GuardarServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("<p>Funcionaa!!!!!!</p>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Necesitarías un WS que te proporcionara la información de cual es el progreso, e ir consultándole periódicamente desde la página web para actualizar la barra de estado. Pero es que tienes una operación monolítica y predecir el tiempo que tardará es muy difícil (si dieras de alta 100 usuarios a la vez, podrías mostrar un 40% y sería razonable suponer que queda un 60% del tiempo, pero aquí solo tienes un único usuario). Una barra de progresos no tiene mucho sentido, recomiendo alguna animación de tipo "En progreso" sin dar más información.

Comment: Además, si no usas Ajax la página web se estará recargando y sencillamente no se mostrará nada de JS...

Comment: Valeee ya entiendo, entonces pondré algún mensaje de en progreso o algo. Muchas gracias jejeje